# LongDeserializer exception while reading KTable using spring-kakfa-stream

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I am trying to read KTable using spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams project. Can we read KTable using spring @StreamListener and all interfaces that spring-cloud-streams provide around messaging.

I am getting LongDeserializer exception while reading KTable.

I am using `springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.RC1'
springBootVersion = '2.0.1.RELEASE'`

The [github link](https://github.com/jaysara/KStreamAnalytics) to the project is available at,
https://github.com/jaysara/KStreamAnalytics

Here is the stacktrace,

```
Exception in thread "panalytics-ac0fa75f-2ae4-4b26-9a04-1f80d1479112-StreamThread-2" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Deserialization exception handler is set to fail upon a deserialization error. If you would rather have the streaming pipeline continue after a deserialization error, please set the default.deserialization.exception.handler appropriately.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordDeserializer.deserialize(RecordDeserializer.java:74)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.addRawRecords(RecordQueue.java:91)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PartitionGroup.addRawRecords(PartitionGroup.java:117)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.addRecords(StreamTask.java:549)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.addRecordsToTasks(StreamThread.java:920)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:821)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:774)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Size of data received by LongDeserializer is not 8
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to uncomment this line: https://github.com/jaysara/KStreamAnalytics/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.properties#L19

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.policyPaidAnalytic.producer.useNativeEncoding=true
```

By default, the binder tries to serialize on the outbound and using `application/json` as the content type. So, in your case, it was going out as json (String) and thats why you were getting that Long serialization exception. By setting the above flag to true, you are asking the binder to stay back and let Kafka Streams serialize natively by using the `LongSerde`.

When you re-run, you might want to clear your topic `policyAnalytic` or use a new topic.

Hope that helps.